# Office UI Fabric Ract Command Giving an error UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts, react, office-ui-fabric-react, fabric

Issue while adding command "npm --save install office-ui-fabric-react"

[image]

NPM Version:

@microsoft/generator-sharepoint@1.0.2

gulp@3.9.1

yo@2.0.2

How to solve this issue?

It gives warning:office-ui-fabric-react@6.20.0 requires a peer of react@>=16.3.2-0 <17.0.0 but none was installed.

Comment: SPFx by default ships with this package, no need to install it separately. What component are you trying to use ?

Comment: I want to use checkbox component. For this i require to import from Office-Fabric UI and this folder doesn't present in Node_Modules. So, i require to use "npm --save install office-ui-fabric-react" command and it gives an error.

Comment: hey Prashant, the lastest fabric ui react is not supported with SPFx v1.0.2 because of typescript issues, so you need to install older version. Try and install `npm -i office-ui-fabric-react@2.20.0 --save`. Could you do that and check ? It contains the checkbox component which you can use

Comment: I solved by below Package JSON version:
 "@types/react": "0.14.46", 

I have degrade my react version.

Answer (score 0):

If solution contains below package json then we can use Fabric react.

```
{
  "name": "navigation",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=0.10.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "gulp bundle",
    "clean": "gulp clean",
    "test": "gulp test"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@microsoft/sp-core-library": "~1.1.0",
    "@microsoft/sp-lodash-subset": "~1.1.0",
    "@microsoft/sp-office-ui-fabric-core": "~1.4.0-0",
    "@microsoft/sp-webpart-base": "~1.1.0",
    "@types/es6-promise": "0.0.33",
    "@types/react": "0.14.46",
    "@types/react-addons-shallow-compare": "0.14.17",
    "@types/react-addons-test-utils": "0.14.15",
    "@types/react-addons-update": "0.14.14",
    "@types/react-dom": "0.14.18",
    "@types/webpack-env": "1.13.1",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "react": "15.4.2",
    "react-dom": "15.4.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@microsoft/sp-build-web": "~1.1.0",
    "@microsoft/sp-module-interfaces": "~1.1.0",
    "@microsoft/sp-webpart-workbench": "~1.1.0",
    "@types/chai": "3.4.34",
    "@types/jquery": "^2.0.48",
    "@types/mocha": "2.2.38",
    "ajv": "~5.2.2",
    "gulp": "~3.9.1"
  }
}
```